# Soapcpp2 not generating ns1 service files

Tags: c++, sdk, vmware, gsoap, vsphere

I am following this link http://www.randombugs.com/linux/vmware-webservice-gsoap.html to use Vsphere sdk with c++.
But I am unable to generate all the required files for the c++ interface.

I already tried using -j tag and different versions of gsoap.

The files generated with the soapcpp2 command are only :

```
Saving soapStub.h annotated copy of the source interface file
Saving soapH.h serialization functions to #include in projects
Saving soap.nsmap namespace mapping table
Saving soapC.cpp serialization functions
```

How to generate the remaining files like:

```
Saving soapClient.cpp
Saving soapClientLib.cpp
Using ns1 service name: VimBinding
Using ns1 service style: document
Using ns1 service encoding: literal
Using ns1 service location: http://localhost:80
Using ns1 schema namespace: urn:vim25
Saving soapVimBindingProxy.h client proxy
Saving VimBinding.nsmap namespace mapping table
```

Comment: Have you ran wsdl2h on the sdk/vim.wsdl file? This file defines service operations. If the WSDL does not define any service operation then NO client code will be generated at all. Check if vim.wsdl has any <porttype> with <operation> with <input> and <output> subelements, as well as a <binding> element.

Comment: What I noticed is that vim.h file generated is of 0kb. On running wsdl2h on vim.wsdl I get error message like "Cannot open 'reflect-messagetypes.xsd' to retrieve schema". How can I resolve this??

Comment: Try `wget https://IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_VMware_VirtualCenter/sdk/reflect-messagetypes.xsd` to save this XSD. Then run `wsdl2h vim.wsdl`.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked to generate some of the files but I am still not getting soapVimBindingProxy.h and VimBinding.nsmap .

Comment: I assume you got all the XSD files on which the WSDL depends? Make sure wsdl2h does not complain about files and URLs it cannot open. After that, run soapcpp2 with option -j to generate the client proxy source code and nsmap files.

Comment: Yes..it worked when I got all the xsd files. Now when I am compiling soapC.cpp, I get an error like " cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes ".